# How to set up redirect on Apache forward proxy?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have Apache 2.4, and I want use it as local proxy server. This is my config of VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.4:1596>
 RewriteEngine  on
 ProxyRequests On

 DocumentRoot "D:/USR/www/proxy"
 ErrorLog "D:/USR/log/proxy/error.log"
 CustomLog "D:/USR/log/proxy/access.log" common
 ServerAdmin webmaster@bot-host
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to redirect traffic. For example, when user go to `https://example1.com/somepage` it will redirected to `https://example25.com/`

I also want to rewrite URL. For example, when user sent request `https://example1.com/somepage?parm1=1596&param2=asdfg789` proxy server will send  `https://example1.com/somepage?parm1=1789&param2=kloxcfjiobvjx9`

I know that this can be done using a [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) function, but I cannot do that. All examples I have seen are about how to redirect in my server pages, but I need a redirecting and rewriting a request on proxy server from other domains.

I don't want to use Squid, I need to do this with Apache.

So, I want to have a local proxy sever with some rules of redirecting and rewriting. Rewriting is very much needed.

So, when user is connected to proxy 127.0.0.4:1596 and go to  `https://example1.com/somepage`, but in fact that server get content from  `example25.com` , and in another case (it is most wanted by me) when user send  `https://example1.com/somepage?parm1=1596&param2=asdfg789` server is really send a  `https://example1.com/somepage?parm1=1789&param2=kloxcfjiobvj‌​x9` an get answer to user.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You say you want to redirect one URL to another, but you want to do it via a proxy. That's not redirection - that's proxying. Do you want the user to appear to be visiting `https://example1.com/somepage` but in fact that server is just silently fetching content from `https://example25.com/`?

Comment: @halfer I want to have a local proxy sever with some rules of redirecting and rewriting. Rewriting is very-very need! 
So, when user(I'am) connected to proxy 127.0.0.4:1596 and go to `https://example1.com/somepage`,  but in fact that server get content from https://example25.com/ , an in another case(it is most wanted by me) when user send `https://example1.com/somepage?parm1=1596&param2=asdfg789` server is really send a `https://example1.com/somepage?parm1=1789&param2=kloxcfjiobvjx9` an get anwer to user

Comment: ^ Merge that into your question please, no point stating it twice `:-)`

Comment: In general, the phrase "rewriting a URL" means that a `Location` header is sent to back the client (with no response body) to ask them to request a different URL. However, if you wish to do it transparently, you can probably do it with the `[P]` proxy flag in `mod_rewrite`. See [these resources here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mod_rewrite+proxy+flag).

Comment: @halfer maybe I don't understand something, but all examples with [P] have proxing/rewrite only some content what user ask from our server, to another. I need to proxying a request to one domain(it is not at my server) to another domain(it too not in my server)/ How do this?

Comment: Ah, so any number of sites are to be proxied through your server? Hmm, OK. You'll need to research how to set up a catch-all virtual host on that server. Nevertheless, it does sound more appropriate to use Squid, and so perhaps you should update your question with why you do not wish to use Squid.

Comment: You might still be able to use mod_rewrite, or mod_proxy, but I think I'd like a good answer to the above question first.

Comment: @halfer my really task -   (transparently) rewrite url for one site, but it site is not on my server, so i want to use proxy for this. Another questions - is my 'abstract' question too learn Apache Server and have a good knowledge about this. I wan't to use  Squid because I newer work with it and it wiil take many time to config it. But I have some knowledge  about Apache and wan to use it. But if this is very hard/not optimal, I can learn and use Squid(I has seen solutions in google).
Too, Apache documetation is bigest an simple, than Squid